# Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") give Error Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

Tags: c#-4.0, office-interop, excel-2010, excel-interop

I have C# application using Microsoft.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Interop.Word.
We have validation that either word or excel one should be open at a time.
When on Excel instance open out side of application with Active Cell - in Writing mode then

I call Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") to crate instance of Excel but at that time it will give error

Marshal.GetActiveObject(progId);

give Error Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

Please give me suggestion so i am able to get object of Excel.

Comment: refer to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Both Excel & Word are single threaded applications.  I've gotten that error before because I had Auto Save on Excel turned on.  You might want to turn that off and see if that fixes the issue.

DD